# why there is unnamed gtag.js cookie along with _ga and _gid cookie? how to rename it from Adobe Launch tag?

Tags: analytics, gtag.js, adobe-launch

why there is unnamed gtag.js cookie along with _ga and _gid cookie? how to rename it from Adobe Launch tag?

[image]